# How to keep table columns name/format with pandas pd.concat()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a table like this,

```
  08:20:00                           PLAYERS  MEMBRESIA  JUGADORES  CARRITOS  OBSERVACION
0   900523  camilo antonio aleman campagnani        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
1  900-561                  josé raúl alemán        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2   900553    nicolas ardito barletta maduro        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
3      NaN                               NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
   08:30:00                       PLAYERS  MEMBRESIA  JUGADORES  CARRITOS  OBSERVACION
0  107546.0        erasmo raúl arias boyd        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
1  103283.0            diego galindo lara        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2  100930.0  luis carlos jaramillo pinzón        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
3       NaN                           NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
   08:40:00                               PLAYERS  MEMBRESIA  JUGADORES  CARRITOS  OBSERVACION
0  102386-1             antonio dominguez alvarez        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
1  102386-2  antonio enrique dominguez de obaldia        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2    102386    maria del carmen de obaldia ortega        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
3    501248                     josé luis alvarez        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
```

After using pd.concat() to join the tables to one DataFrame, it removes the individual column heading.
Result:

```
  08:20:00                           PLAYERS  MEMBRESIA  JUGADORES  CARRITOS  OBSERVACION
0   900523  camilo antonio aleman campagnani        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
1  900-561                  josé raúl alemán        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2   900553    nicolas ardito barletta maduro        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
3      NaN                               NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
0  107546.0        erasmo raúl arias boyd        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
1  103283.0            diego galindo lara        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2  100930.0  luis carlos jaramillo pinzón        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
3       NaN                           NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
0  102386-1             antonio dominguez alvarez        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
1  102386-2  antonio enrique dominguez de obaldia        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2    102386    maria del carmen de obaldia ortega        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
3    501248                     josé luis alvarez        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
```

I want to retain the format as it is.
What I am trying to do is read the HTML document, pass it to pandas read_html function, and export it as excel.

Basically, I want to retain this format. and I am relatively new to pandas.

Comment: there is something unique about your data - **playerID** column is labelled as a timestamp.  do you want to keep this timestamp?

Comment: I want the data frame to look exactly like the first one not the second one. The second is what I get after concat() @Rob Raymond

Comment: so you want the first column to be **08:20:00** for all rows?

Comment: have provided update to answer that just forces all column names across all data frames to be the same

Comment: No I want the data frame to remain as the first table I posted in the question. The second data frame is what I get after concating. It's a multiple table, where each: 08:20:00                           PLAYERS  MEMBRESIA  JUGADORES  CARRITOS  OBSERVACION is a table head with related data in tbody. Like I said it's multiple html table. That I just want to preserve the way it is without swallowing it's table thread for each table.

Comment: well I have no idea why you are doing `concat()` if you do not want data from any other table

Comment: I want to join multiple table to a single dataframe and preserve their format without merging the column names.

Comment: ok - you consider the columns as rows.   I've updated supplementary to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the first column of each dataframe is different.  Appears as if it is a timestamp
- copy it to a column using `assign()`
- `rename()` it so all the data frames are consistent

```
data = ["""  08:20:00                           PLAYERS  MEMBRESIA  JUGADORES  CARRITOS  OBSERVACION
0   900523  camilo antonio aleman campagnani        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
1  900-561                  josé raúl alemán        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2   900553    nicolas ardito barletta maduro        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
3      NaN                               NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN""",
"""   08:30:00                       PLAYERS  MEMBRESIA  JUGADORES  CARRITOS  OBSERVACION
0  107546.0        erasmo raúl arias boyd        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
1  103283.0            diego galindo lara        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2  100930.0  luis carlos jaramillo pinzón        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
3       NaN                           NaN        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN""",
"""   08:40:00                               PLAYERS  MEMBRESIA  JUGADORES  CARRITOS  OBSERVACION
0  102386-1             antonio dominguez alvarez        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
1  102386-2  antonio enrique dominguez de obaldia        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
2    102386    maria del carmen de obaldia ortega        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN
3    501248                     josé luis alvarez        NaN        NaN       NaN          NaN"""]

dfs = {f"df{i}":pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),sep="\s\s+", engine="python") for i,data in enumerate(data)}

df = pd.concat([df.assign(TIMESTAMP=df.columns[0]).rename(columns={df.columns[0]:"PLAYERID"}) for df in dfs.values()])
```

#### output

|  | PLAYERID | PLAYERS | MEMBRESIA | JUGADORES | CARRITOS | OBSERVACION | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 900523 | camilo antonio aleman campagnani | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:20:00 |
| 1 | 900-561 | josé raúl alemán | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:20:00 |
| 2 | 900553 | nicolas ardito barletta maduro | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:20:00 |
| 3 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:20:00 |
| 0 | 107546.0 | erasmo raúl arias boyd | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:30:00 |
| 1 | 103283.0 | diego galindo lara | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:30:00 |
| 2 | 100930.0 | luis carlos jaramillo pinzón | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:30:00 |
| 3 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:30:00 |
| 0 | 102386-1 | antonio dominguez alvarez | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:40:00 |
| 1 | 102386-2 | antonio enrique dominguez de obaldia | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:40:00 |
| 2 | 102386 | maria del carmen de obaldia ortega | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:40:00 |
| 3 | 501248 | josé luis alvarez | nan | nan | nan | nan | 08:40:00 |

#### supplementary

Column names are wanted as rows.  `concat()` them back in and `concat()` all data frames.

```
# put the column back into rows and use generic column names...
pd.concat([pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values).T, 
                      df.rename(columns={c:i for i,c in enumerate(df.columns)})]) 
           for df in dfs.values()])
```

Comment: I had to modify the code for it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
final = pd.concat([pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values).T, 
              df.rename(columns={c:i for i,c in enumerate(df.columns)})]) 
   for df in dfs])
```

as dfs is a list of DataFrames extracted from html tables it doesn't have the .values() method on it.